# Date difference in mysql

Tags: sql, mysql

In a mysql table for a date column(login_time), i need to get the logins for

last 30 days, last 60 days.

Is there any way to do that?

Thanks.

Comment: Example of expected output?  The other columns in the table too, please...

Comment: Am trying to get last 30 days logged in uers, last 60 days using login_time column.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this will give you the rows from the table where login_time is within the last 60 days:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE login_time >= SUBDATE(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 60 DAY)
```

similarly with 30 days.

Comment: Note the addDate (3x`D`) and 60 `DAY` (not "dayS")

Comment: Thanks, will it give me login_time of last 30 days logged in users?

Comment: Not good as query optimizer cannot used index by login_time and need arithmetic for every record. Better to apply adddate to curdate()